# CSS for carousel of elements (container has fixed width, scrollable area has infinite width)

Tags: html, css

What CSS is required to make it so a viewport can have an infinitely wide list inside of it?

```
<div class='viewport'>
  <ul class='scrollable-content'>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

This doesn't seem like it should require javascript.  It's gotta be something simple, just can't wrap my mind around it at the moment.

Comment: You want the `<li>` items to stretch infinitely off horizontally? yet the container have a fixed width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/vJgtM/

Comment: the items inside `<li>` are images and text, something like [this](http://zendold.lojcomm.com.br/icarousel/example3.asp), but he has hardcoded a width in his css.

Comment: @viatropos so, like so? http://jsfiddle.net/n9Sz8/7/ you could implement your own scrolling feature.

Answer (score 1):

This might work also (http://jsfiddle.net/vJgtM/7/):

**CSS**:

```
div.viewport {
    width: 500px;
    overflow: auto;
}

div.viewport ul {
    width: 100%;
     white-space: nowrap;
}

div.viewport ul li {
    display: inline;
}
```